# JQuery - Select by attribute?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

This works in Opera but apparently nothing else.

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="iphone" value="checked" checked="checked"  />
<input type="checkbox" name="photocart" value="checked" checked="checked"  />
```

JS

```
$("input[name=iphone]").attr('checked', 'checked');
$("input[name=photocart]").attr('checked', 'checked');
$("input[name=iphone]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$("input[name=photocart]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

I have also tried the following to no avail.

```
$("input[name|=iphone]").attr('checked', 'checked');
$("input[name|=photocart]").attr('checked', 'checked');
$("input[name|=iphone]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$("input[name|=photocart]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');

$("[name=iphone]").attr('checked', 'checked');
$("[name=photocart]").attr('checked', 'checked');
$("[name=iphone]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$("[name=photocart]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');

$("[name|=iphone]").attr('checked', 'checked');
$("[name|=photocart]").attr('checked', 'checked');
$("[name|=iphone]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$("[name|=photocart]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

No joy on any of them. Any ideas on how I can get this going?

EDIT :- Epic failed on the copying of the HTML SORRY!

Comment: The markup you posted has the `name` "hosting", but none of your selectors are looking for this, can you post the markup that this JS is looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify it like this:

```
$('input[name=hosting][checked]')
```

See the [Jquery multiple selector page](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>First off, you have two elements named "hosting", but you aren't using "input[name=hosting]".</strike>

Your HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="iphone" value="checked" checked="checked"  />
<input type="checkbox" name="photocart" value="checked" checked="checked"  />
```

JS (that *should* work):

```
$('input[name=iphone]').attr('checked', true);
$('input[name=photocart]').attr('checked', true);
$('input[name=iphone]').attr('disabled', true);
$('input[name=photocart]').attr('disabled', true);
```

Keep in mind that if you have more than one element with name "iphone" or "photocart" that jQuery will change their attributes as well.

Use `true` or `false` instead of 'checked' or 'disabled' for the attribute values. Remember, you're manipulating the DOM, so it's different than having `<input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" />`.

Comment: Sorry, pasted the wrong html :S. Can you look again please. This has been fixed

Comment: Also, I don't have much control over the html so I would prefer if this was a purely jQuery solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
//for each one
$("input[name=photocart] :checked").val();
$("input[name=iphone] :checked").val();

//general, used with an event
result = $(this).is(":checked");

//general, used with a css class in common (add a class="checkable" to your target inputs)
$(".checkable:checked").each(function() {
    result += this.value;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, pasted the wrong html :S. Can you look again please. This has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The [attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors) `[name=val]` matches all elements that have an attribute *name* that’s value is exactly `val`. In opposite to that, `[name|=val]` matches all elements that have an attribute *name* that’s value either being exactly "`val`" or beginning with "`val`" immediately followed by "`-`". The latter is rather intended to be used with a language codes (e.g. `[lang|=en]` matches `lang="en-US"`). So use the former selector for an exact match.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can also go basic and do these like this:

```
if ($("input[name=iphone]")[0].checked) // returns true or false depending on the value
if $("input[name=photocart]")[0].checked) 
if ($("input[name=iphone]")[0].disabled) // returns boolean value
if ($("input[name=photocart]")[0].disabled)

$("input[name=iphone]")[0].checked = true;// sets the check to true (checked) 
$("input[name=photocart]")[0].attr('checked', true); 
$("input[name=iphone]")[0].disabled = false;// enables the input control
$("input[name=photocart]")[0].attr('disabled', true);
```

Another cool trick, set the value to what it is NOT at present which acts like a toogle:

```
$("input[name=iphone]")[0].checked = !$("input[name=iphone]")[0].checked;
```

EDIT: example to set all checked boxes to unchecked:

```
$("input:checked")[0] = false;// single
$('input:checked').each(function() {
    this.checked = true;
});
```

NOTE IF you give them a class called "mycheckbox" even simpler:

```
var toggle_click = false; 
$(function() {  
  $('.mycheckbox').click(function() { 
    $('.mycheckbox').each().checked = !this.checked; 
    toggle_click = !toggle_click; 
  }); 
});
```

AND IF it is checked, uncheck it:

```
$('.cptIcdCheckbox:checked').each(function() {
            this.checked = !this.checked;
 });
```

I use this technique if I have a list of checkboxes and a "header" checkbox to uncheck them all or check them all depending upon the "group header" checkbox value and it's click and/or change event.

Comment: `$(...)` returns an array... would you not have to do `$(...)[0].checked` and so forth to get the actual DOM object?

Comment: @Cory Larson - in short yes, hence the .each in the two later examples.  The simplistic one only works if you only have one from the set - editing the example.