# how to check if an id attribute exists on a table row using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm assigning an `id` attribute to a table row after an ajax call. At another function call I need to check if this row has an id assigned and I m trying the following code but keep getting error on this line of script. `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

```
if (typeof($(this).closest('tr').Attr('id'))!='undefined') {
        rowId = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
    }
```

I've seen similar questions and solutions and have tried various combinations but don't know why I keep getting error on this line.

Comment: Typo... `Attr != attr`

Comment: Flagging to close because the problem is a simple typographical error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery - Select by attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717264/jquery-select-by-attribute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method name is `attr()` - note the lowercase `a`. You also don't need to use `typeof`. An empty string or `null` return false when used in a comparison, so you can simply use the method call in an `if` condition:

```
if ($(this).closest('tr').attr('id')) {
    rowId = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
    // do something with rowId...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your selector seems to not be selecting an element, hence the undefined.

You need to make sure that $(this) is actually set correctly.